# Pull to refresh in Main Activity that contains fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, pull-to-refresh

i have googled alot but didn't find anything that suitable answer for me.

I want to implement **pull to refresh**. I have gone through all below links but every where they have given the example for simple ListView or ScrollView in Activity.

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh

https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

http://guides.thecodepath.com/android/Implementing-Pull-to-Refresh

Here i have an activity that contains **4 Fragments** and i want to implement pull to refresh. How can i do it.

#### Any kind of help will be extremely appreciated.

Below is my Activity XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/homePageBackground"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/announcementHomefragment"
    android:name="in.test.app.AnnouncementFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/homePageBackground" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/homePageBackground" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/new_list"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/newshomefragment"
            android:name="in.test.app.NewsFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="265dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/newsTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/newshomefragment"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/product_in_home"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/proCategoryhomefragment"
            android:name="in.test.app.CategoryFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/productTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trainingTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/proCategoryhomefragment"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/trainings_in_home"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/trainingfragment"
            android:name="in.test.app.TrainingFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/trainingTitle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**EDITED:**

Now i am using **SwipeRefreshLayout**. It is working fine. But when i am scrolling my scroll view down and trying to go up it is not going up, it is not working again it is refreshing. please suggest me how to get this thing accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a class which **extends** `SwipeRefreshLayout` and **override** the method `canChildScrollUp()`. Return true when you want scroll down for `ListView`.

For example,

```
@override.
boolean canChildScrollUp()
{
return Listview.getFirstVisibleItemPostion()!=0;
}
```

Comment: as you can see above i have not list view in xml. So should i do?